# Which chapters of Bhagavad Gita should be read for Shanti of the departed ancestors?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, rituals, death

What are the specific chapters of Bhagavad Gita that should be read for the Shanti of the departed ancestors/ family members ?

Comment: Congrats @G.kumar on your first post on H.SE! I would like to say that this is a Great Question! +1 to you (and Akshay S for editing).

Answer (score 3):

Ninth chapter of gita is sufficient because it has following verse:

> यान्ति देवव्रता देवान् पितृ़न्यान्ति पितृव्रताः।
>   भूतानि यान्ति भूतेज्या यान्ति मद्याजिनोऽपि माम्।।9.25।।
>
> 9.25. The votaries of the gods attain the gods; the votaries of the manes attain the manes; performers of sacrifices for the goblins attain the goblins; also the performers of sacrifices for Me attain Me.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! You should add some explanation about how this verse is useful. Take a [tour] and visit [help] for further information on how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, people do not generally read Bhagavad Gita for Pitr Shanti.

However, I did [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31648/16773) to a similar question, which was on prayaschitta for not performing rites and that also comes under the category fo Pitr Shanti. The following activities are recommended for Pitr shanti, apart from Shraddha karma. These are mentioned in a book named "Pithru Poojanam" (there is no online link for this book, sorry), but you can read about the accomplished author [Brahmasri Rajagopala Ganapaadi](http://vaithikasri.com/aboutus.htm).

> 1. paaraayana of Srimad Ramayana for 9 nine days
> 2. paaraayana Srimad Bhagavatam for 7 days.
> 3. Respective Veda paaraayana through qualified scholars
> 4. Bathing in holy rivers after proper sankalpam for the sathagati of the departed
> 5. Donating black till/sesame seeds or rice with sesame seeds or black urad dall to impoverished people
> 6. Donating dress or food on the maasika days to poor people
> 7. Donating food and dress for laborers

Comment: OP specifically asks chapters from Bhagavadgita but your answer doesn't quote Bhavagavad gita and says "I do not know if they read Bhagavad Gita for Pitr Shanti .". How does this answer question?

Comment: @TheDestroyer There. Changed the answer a bit. Now does it answer the question?The answer is they don't read BG. Instead, the other activities are recommended.

Comment: if you want to answer "No", you  can check this meta post. https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/612/3500

Comment: @TheDestroyer This is not a yes or no question.

Comment: "As far as I know, people do not generally read Bhagavad Gita for Pitr Shanti." This looks like your opinion. You can answer saying there's no chapter in BG which talks about Shanti of departed souls as mentioned in that meta post.  Other methods are not relevant to question since OP asks shanti from BG.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes it is my informed opinion. And the next part is relevant to the context of the question since pitr shanti and prayaschitta go hand in hand. Go ahead and flag as not an answer if you think otherwise.

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee yes. I am aware of chanting BG on Shradda day in some places. That's the reason asked him to quote his answer citing original BG only. Answer can be right or wrong (depending on users perspective), but this is actually not answering except first line which also looks like opinion.

Comment: @Ambi it was already flagged and that's the reason i asked to edit it. OP only asks chapters from BG. You should  either say some chapters names which should be chanted or say no chapters are recited during Shradda ceremonies. Other methods are not relevant to what OP asked.

Comment: @TheDestroyer  I don't see a need to remove it because I see contextually it is related. I can't assume a negative... that the OP doesn't want to know anything other than about BG. OP can choose which answer is correct anyways.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89121/discussion-on-answer-by-ambi-which-chapters-of-bhagavad-gita-should-be-read-for).

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee " Nowhere is it written that the above prescription has to be followed for Pitrishanti so far as i know." The user already a cited a book written by a Ghanapati in which the ghanapati says that. So, it's not right to say no such thing exists. Better to remove or modify  (only a mod can do) that comment. It could be misleading.

Comment: Ok. @ParthaBanerjee You can talk to me in the above chatroom. See Pandya's comment or in Hinduism room. That should have been more clearer because nowhere doesn't mean only in Gita. You can also edit your comment within 5 minutes. Let's continue the discussion there if you want to continue.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma sorry this time also i cd nt connect to chat. i hv dlted to avd misunderstanding. btw i saw that link and dont think this ghanapati has that credibility so that his rule has to be followed.there must be some scriptural refvas its related to kriyakarma.so  ghanapati's is smthng like deshachara or advice at best

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know,chanting of the whole Gita is done on the sraddha day in some parts of India, particularly Bengal. A brahmin is appointed especially for the paatha of Gita. I did not get any direct scriptural order as its cause.But I think Gita is chanted for Pitri-shanti on sraddha day because

1. In the Gita-Mahtmya, Lord Vishnu says(Gita, Udbodhan,page 408):

> Wherever is Gita read, all sacred places like Prayag appear there.All the rishis, yogis,Pannagas, Narada, Uddhava, the gopalas and the gopis appear there. I also appear there.

Bhagavan Visnu or Hari is known as destoyer of all sins("Sarvapaapaharo Harih") and bestower of Mukti("Mukum muktim dadaati iti Mukundah"). It is believed that our souls of our dead ancestors appear to accept pinda on the Sraddha day. I think it is believed following the Gitamahatmya that the presence of the teerthas, rishis, devotees and God Himslf will be more than enough for destroying all the sins of the departed soul and getting his or her the supreme upliftment.

2. At the same time, Gita repeatedly says about the immortality of the soul. I think this also gives solace to the wards that their father or mother are still living at least in sukshnma form and so not lost forever.

But I repeat, these are local customs and beliefs and so vary from region to region. In Bengal, a copy of Gita is given to 12 brahmins along with some other daanas.

Comment: What about giving charity of copies of Gitas to Brahmins?

Comment: @Rickross that i think is a local custom

Comment: You can post ur local custom .. and say in which region it is followed .. in any case donating Brahmins  something at the end of any rituals is mandatory

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All, I got to read that chapters 7, 12& 15 for pitru Shanthi.

https://iskcondesiretree.com/m/discussion?id=2103886%3ATopic%3A1160055

http://navdurganavratri.blogspot.com/2013/09/read-story-first-and-then-read-7th.html?m=1